# Safely Deleting a Directory Only If It ISN'T a Mount Point

Tags: filesystems, mount, directory, rm, unmounting

Unfortunately I'm being forced to work with a piece of software that handles automatically mounting and unmounting a network volume very poorly; it has an annoying tendency to leave a directory where the mount point was, but can't cope properly with that being the case when mounting the volume again later (it's **supposed** to tidy up but often doesn't).

Naturally I'm on at the developers to get that fixed, but in the meantime I need to do something to tidy up the mount point(s) myself.

So essentially what I need to do is remove the directory, but only if it **isn't** currently a mount point (as I don't want to delete the volume's contents by accident).

Now, I can get the device ID of the directory and compare it to the device ID of root easily enough, but there's a possibility of a race-condition if I use such a comparison, i.e- if the volume is mounted between checking device IDs and calling `rm -r /mnt/point`.

Are there any alternatives? I was intrigued by the possibility of using the `find` command's `-xdev` option, but I'm not sure how I would actually provide a point of comparison, as `find /mnt/point -xdev` won't work as the target and its contents are the same device.

Also, using `rmdir` on the assumption that the leftover folder will always be empty seems unreliable, as on some systems a mount point may have a file inside; macOS for example leaves an `.autodiskmounted` file inside. While I *could* create a list of such cases and handle them, it'd be nice (and hopefully useful to others) to have a more general purpose solution for future reference, if such a thing is possible.

Comment: Not sure about Mac OS but on Linux, you can run "mount" on it's own to get a list of mounted file systems. You can then use something like awk to parse the directories and compare them to the one in question.

Comment: What's your OS platform? (Please tag it.) We don't have GNU utilities on Mac systems or embedded Linux-based systems that would otherwise be expected as standard on full Linux-based systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the directory is a mount point, it will be busy and you shouldn't be able to rename it.

```
$ sudo mv /mnt /mnt.old
mv: cannot move '/mnt' to '/mnt.old': Device or resource busy
```

If it's just a regular directory, you should be able to rename it.

```
$ sudo mv /mnt /mnt.old
```

If the move succeeds, re-create the mount directory and delete the renamed directory.  Optionally, you can validate the renamed directory is part of the filesystem you expect before removal.

Comment: Looks like we may have a winner! Super compatible and like all good solutions it's so simple I'm now kicking myself for not thinking of it on my own! It looks like the "can't move a mountpoint" condition applies to all unix-y systems I have at the moment (Macs, a NAS, couple of servers). Unless there's an exception to this somewhere it seems like a good general purpose solution.

Answer (score 1):

***If you are using Linux***

You can test if a directory is a mount point using [`mountpoint`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/mountpoint.1.html).

To avoid mount point appearing/disappearing between test and `rm -r`, you need to run the script in a separate [*mount namespace*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) with [*private subtree*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) (mounts do not propagate from/to new namespace). This can be accomplished with [`unshare`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/unshare.1.html).

```
unshare -m --propagation private -- "<delete script>"
```

Everything in same script:

```
#!/bin/sh

unshare -m --propagation private -- sh -e <<EOF

if ! mountpoint -q "<path>"; then
    rm -r "<path>"
fi

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `rmdir` a directory that's not empty or one that's a mountpoint. So this will satisfy your requirement:

```
rm -f mountpoint/.autodiskmounted    # MacOS cookie
rmdir mountpoint 2>/dev/null
```

If you're running in a script with *exit on error* set, you can use `rmdir ... || true`. (Note that `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` is of little use, because we will get an uncaught error when attempting to remove a mountpoint.)

I should point out that I don't have access to a Mac system so I cannot test whether the `.autodiskmounted` file is present when the filesystem really is mounted, or whether it's a placeholder for when the filesystem is unmounted.